# When I use a subsurface modifier, a weird line shows up that hides the mesh

Tags: mesh, subdivision-surface

When I insert the subsurface modifier, a weird line shows up and the mesh is removed. Every time I use the modifier, a line cuts through the mesh.
[image]

Comment: please share your blend file https://blend-exchange.com

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to go to menu *Edit > Preferences > Viewport > Subdivision* and then turn off or untick *GPU Subdivision*.

[image]